# Java Struts call another action after executed action finished

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action

I'm using Java and Struts2.
In my struts.xml configure file i have blow config.

```
<action name="copyTestSuite" class="testSuiteAction"
    method="copyTestSuite">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/FormSuccessfulWithOutCloseWindow.jsp
    </result>
</action>
```

After i executed action copyTestSuite, the default page will go to FormSuccessfulWithOutCloseWindow.jsp. and this page is just used to redirect to previous page.

But i want to let it go to another action matched page directly. How can i do this?

Below is another action toUpdateTestSuite i want to redirect to:

```
<action name="toUpdateTestSuite" class="testSuiteAction"
    method="toUpdateTestSuite">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/testsuite/updateTestSuite.jsp
    </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  this `<result type="redirectAction"></result>`

```
<action name="copyTestSuite" class="testSuiteAction"
method="copyTestSuite">
<result type="redirectAction">/newAction.action</result>
</action>
```

Comment: To redirect to another *Action*, `redirectAction` is *preferable* to `redirect`, that is generally use to link external URLs or other non-action, non-jsp resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect using something like:

```
<action name="copyTestSuite" class="testSuiteAction" method="copyTestSuite">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">toUpdateTestSuite</param>        
    </result>
</action>
```