# struts 2 xml mapping is not working for different class?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am trying to map mysql mapping using hibernate. I have given an action in my jsp page which maps to `tweetAction` class's `putMessage()` method. My problem is the mapping is working for `userAction` class's methods. But when I have added `tweetAction` class, its not working at all.
I just want this flow to enter `putMessage()` that's why I have entered a SysOut method just to display it on the console

This is my struts.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">

        <action name="login" method="isAuthentic" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/home.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result> 
        </action>

        <action name="addUser" method="add" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
        </action>
        <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="searchUser" method="search" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/display.jsp</result>
        </action>


        <action name="message" method="putMessage" class="com.vaannila.web.TweetAction">
            <result name="success" >/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

This is my TweetAction.java:

```
package com.vaannila.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.vaannila.dao.TweetDAO;
import com.vaannila.dao.TweetDAOImpl;
import com.vaannila.dao.UserDAO;
import com.vaannila.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import com.vaannila.domain.Tweet;
import com.vaannila.domain.User;

public class TweetAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Tweet> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6659925652584240539L;

    private Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    private User user = new User();
    private List<Tweet> tweetList = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    private TweetDAO tweetDAO = new TweetDAOImpl();
    private boolean isAuthentic = false;
    public Tweet getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String putMessage()
    {
        System.out.println("inside putMessage");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String tweet()
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/twitter</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.vaannila.domain.User" />
        <mapping class="com.vaannila.domain.Tweet" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my sample Home.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>What's on your mind?</h2>
<s:form action="message">
        <s:textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="75"  Placeholder="Enter here..." />
    <s:submit  />  <!-- type="image" src="tweet.jpg" align="center" -->
</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml:

```
    <action name="login" method="isAuthentic" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success">/temp.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result> 
    </action>

    <action name="addUser" method="add" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
    </action>
    <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success">/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="searchUser" method="search" class="com.vaannila.web.UserAction">
        <result name="success">/display.jsp</result>
    </action>


    <action name="message" method="putMessage" class="com.vaannila.web.TweetAction">
        <result name="success">/temp.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: But you didn't tell what is not working. Do you have exception stacktrace? You are probably doing something ridicules wrong because not objects are initialized when they needed.

Comment: The jsp action cannot enter the methods of TweetAction class but it is able to access the UserAction class methods.

Comment: That was already said, do you have anything to add?

Comment: Do you have a connection to database?

Comment: I have used googleAPIs for connection to database using session and trasaction objects, annotations and hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: But you misconfigured it in this question.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. What URL are you hitting? What happens? The `redirect` should be a `redirectAction` if you want to hit the `tweet` message.

Comment: @DaveNewton First you need to invoke `putMessage`, `redirectAction` subclasses `redirect`.

Comment: @RomanC What is misconfigured? I am sorry but i am new to struts-hibernate. So I might have done some stupid mistakes. But from my understanding this is what should happen. On clicking "submit" button in the jsp, it should check in the struts.xml file what has to be done for the 'message' action. The 'message' action in struts.xml points to the putMessage() method of TweetAction.java class. So it should go inside the putMessage() method and should print "inside put message" in the console. Did I miss anything??

Comment: @user3387006 `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getModel() method in TweetAction. The return value is null, it is wrong I think. Because ModelInterceptor can not encapsulate the data into the null entity.

Modification:

```
public Tweet getModel()
{
return tweet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Java Struts call another action after executed action finsihed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998091/java-struts-call-another-action-after-executed-action-finsihed/26998218#26998218)

Check above

you should try `<result type="redirectAction">/listTweet</result>` dont forget to put `/` before action name

Comment: No. I removed the redirectAction. Now i am directly going to home.jsp.